# Variable names in .ckpt file of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, restore

I have the following variable in my Convnet:

```
conv1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=filter_shape, mean = mu, stddev = sigma),name='W1')
```

and save the model when it is trained. For figuring out the value of `conv1_W` once training is finished, I use the `print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file` function introduced in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py). However, in addition to `W1`, I see `W1_1` and `W1/Adam` are also saved in the ckpt file. What are these variables exactly? How are they different from `W1`?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code describing your Convnet and how you are saving it? It will make it easier to reproduce your circumstances

Comment: When I run the same TF model repeatedly in Jupyter, TF appends var names with _n for each nth run. From what I understand, if you serialize without explicitly stating which variables to serialize, TF will save all of them, so could this explain W1_1? Not sure about /Adam though...

Comment: that happens when you try to create `W1` twice